# What do you call a "redundant" parameter?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, terminology

In maximum likelihood estimation, including an additional parameter in the model usually results in a higher likelihood value.  It is possible, though, to add an additional parameter that doesn't change the likelihood.

A trivial example would be the model $\mu_i = \theta_1 \theta_2$, where clearly either one of the $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$ is superfluous.

Is there a technical term for such a parameter, or can I call it simply a redundant parameter?

Comment: So which one of the parameters $\theta_1,\theta_2$ you want to call a name? What I'm alluding to is in your example you can't just single out one of them. The problem is not in one of the parameters but in the model specification itself

Comment: @Aksakal Yes, you're right, but you could speak of the model as "having a ____ parameter," without referring to any parameter in particular.

Comment: The *model* could be under-identified (other alternatives: just identified and over-identified). I don't know about the parameters, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would call such a model non-identifiable, or you might call the problematic parameter(s) itself non-identifiable.

Comment: Will non-separable (rather than non-identifiable) work?

Comment: @ZahavaKor No, I don't think so, "separability" has a different meaning in statistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability